# How can I create that sharp, intense sound when placing a stone?

Tags: go, goban, aesthetics

No matter the material (board, stones) being used, pros are able to create a very sharp, loud, intense and beautiful sound when placing a stone (which immediately sits perfectly placed on its intersection). I've been playing for a few years and taught myself how to place stones, but I've never been able to constantly reproduce that sound.

Do you know the secret behind it? Or is it really just experience by placing millions and millions of stones?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the stone is held properly it rests on your index finger being held by your middle finger.

You place the stone on the board hitting it with your index finger and the stone. It has been suggested this first sound is the "bah" sound in the Korean name for the game (Baduk/Paduk).

At the same time, you push the stone with your middle finger so it slides off your index finger. This causes it to snap onto the board producing a distinctive click (the "dook" sound).

Answer (score 2):

A large part of it is probably the quality of the board.  The table boards professionals play on in major events have a pyramid shape cut out of the bottom.

There are three widely accepted reasons for this:

- To make sure the inside of the board is dry so it doesn't warp.
- To improve the clack sound made when playing a stone.
- To hold the blood of kibitzers who interfere with the game.

Comment: Don't agree since I've seen (heard, rather) this on normal wooden boards, too.